# Dynamic Route at Root Level in Next.JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, routes, url-routing

I am trying to create route for the product page and product listing page at the root level in next.js but I am not sure how it will work because anything in the route will go to route level file. I have a navigation in the header for categories which works gender based.

Below is the sample url of the product page.

**https://www.sample.com/moon-boot-x-stranger-things-upside-down-boots-black-fabric-women-flats-22hgbe.html**

For example I have created one file on pages/[slug].js

Below is the sample url for product listing page ( women is gender and dynamic )

**https://www.sample.com/women/pumps.html**

**Problem Statement**

I cannot create folders for routing inside page directory as all urls are dynamic and does not container static folder name.

I want to figure out the way to achieve this on the application level.

I have also explored middleware.js but I do not have anything static to identify the request to reroute to the specific folder.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken you want to create static routes but you can't because you have dynamic route in the root. Personally I wouldn't use dynamic routing at root, instead I would put something like `/gender/[slug].js`.

However, based on [nextjs docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#caveats), you should be able to put static routes at the same level as a dynamic route and they (static routes) will take precedence.

If you mean you want to put a static routes inside the dynamic route, delete the `[slug].js` and instead create a folder `[slug]` and inside it put your static.js files. So it should look likes this

```
/pages/[slug]/pumps.js
```

Comment: yes, you are right. i do not want to put dynamic route at the root because as you can see in the url I have mentioned in the question, I have slug to product page and would like to use it inside any route under page directory. But I am not getting any way to achieve it.

Comment: @H.Husain just updated my answer again, I think I got what you want after I saw your edit on the question..

Comment: So you mean to say I can have 2 routes on root and folder level like below : 

https://www.sample.com/moon-boot-x-stranger-things-upside-down-boots-black-fabric-women-flats-22hgbe.html

`/pages/[slug]/index.js`

https://www.sample.com/women/pumps.html

`/pages/[gender]/[category]/index.js`

Kindly suggest and confirm further. Thanks

Comment: 1- You can have a dynamic route (one) and static routes (many) in the same path (root or other path) -> but don't use both `/pages/[slug]/index.js` & `/pages/[gender]/[category]/index.js`

Comment: 2- You can use `/pages/[gender]/[category]/index.js` and `/pages/home.js` for example at the same time.. please do give it a test and let me know if I can explain this more.

Comment: @H.Husain please consider upvoting and accepting my answer if you think I answered your question, if not, please let me know if I have not understood you correctly or my answer is not clear or buggy.

Comment: Sure, I will implement and check. Thanks a lot for your answer. Currently my routes does not work the way I need.